# Tool for designing a pastel green to red colour scheme with a range of 10?

Tags: color, software-recommendation

Is there a website or tool that will allow me to choose a group of equally separated list of 10 colours from pastel green to pastel red to be used as the background colour in the cells of a table?

Comment: Hi 20050, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. What have you tried that didn't work? In order to give you a good answer, we'd like to see your question to show at least as much effort as a good answer to it would. Telling us what you have tried and what your problems with that were, increases the chance of a good answer manyfold. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the question now: long story short, after much Googling, I haven't been able to find a website for the purpose of my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you come across this site in your Googling: http://www.colorhexa.com?
It has the ability to generate gradients between two colours, but it generates them in 12 steps rather than 10. If you fiddle around with your colours, you might be able to get the colours right.

I also found this website: http://www.perbang.dk/rgbgradient/, which has less features than the other one, but you can specify the number of steps in your gradient.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Adobe Illustrator** and it's **Blend** feature for this. I don't know if you have Illustrator available, but I do this all the time for color transitions.

[image]

Finally choose `Object > Expand Appearance` and you'll have 10 objects ranging in color from green to red. Simply sample those colors or add them to the Swatch Panel and save as `.ase` for other Adobe apps.